# Play music tones based on keyboard input at runtime

Tags: python, python-2.7, audio, pyaudio

I have a project in which I need to play a song at runtime, with the rhythm being determined by the user by pressing some keyboard key, which will later be used with a MaKey MaKey.

My goal is to create a list of tones or frequencies that will be represent some song (eg: `song = ['C#', 'D', 'B', 'F', .....]`). Then I will probably use PyGame to catch keyboard events to play one these notes one by one in a while loop.

My problem is that I didn't found any suitable python music lib to do such thing, or I didn't dig enough the ones I found to find a proper solution.
Does anyone can suggest me a python lib that can help me create musical tone list and play it at runtime?

Comment: I think that not exist it in python, start creating some pruse senoidal tones to play in realt-ime based in your input keyborad

Comment: @ederwander I found this github repo that does what I need. Its not a lib, but the code was very usefull https://github.com/akajuvonen/beep-reader-player